# Boost Spirit parser rule to detect special endings in a statement

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

This small sample grammar just parse this statements

```
a        <--special (but ok because rule in grammer)
a()
a.b      <--special
a.b()
a.b().c  <--special
a().b.c()
a().b    <--special
```

all cases with non () at the end are special and should be separate rules in spirit. Only the rule (special case 1) is correct so far. How to define a rule which capture all other cases without () at the end ?

```
  lvalue_statement =

    (
      name >> +(
          (lit('(') >> paralistopt  >> lit(')')[_normal_action_call]
        | (lit('.') >> name)                   [_normal_action_dot]
        )
      
      | name                                   [_special_action_]  // special case 1
    )
```

another sample to explain what "special" means, you can see that the ROOT node should have the special AST Node or action

```
a.b         -> SPECIAL_DOT(a,b)
a.b.c       -> SPECIAL_DOT(a,NORMAL_DOT(b,c))
a(para).b.c -> SEPCIAL_DOT(NORMAL_DOT(CALL(a,para),c)
```

Comment: I see only one rule. What is the special rule?

Comment: To the edit: is it "special" if it is the "trailing limb" only? Surely you can detect that from the ast during evaluation?

Comment: yes i can detect this in the AST .. but i would prefer to handle this inside boost and create a different AST in this case with this SPECIAL_DOT node

Answer (score 1):

I'm quite averse of so many semantic actions¹.

I also think that's not your problem.

In language terms, you'd expect `a.b` to be member dereference, `a()` to be invocation, and hence `a.b()` would be invoation of `a.b` after the member dereference.

In that sense, `a.b` is the normal case, because it doesn't do invocation. `a.b()` would be "more special" in the sense that it is the same PLUS invocation.

I'd phrase my expression grammar to reflect this:

```
lvalue = name >> *(
        '.' >> name
      | '(' >> paralistopt >> ')'
    );
```

This parses everything. Now you might go with semantic actions or attribute propagation

### Semantic Actions #1

```
auto lvalue = name [ action("normal") ] >> *(
        '.' >> name [ action("member_access") ]
      | ('(' >> paralistopt >> ')') [ action("call") ]
    );
```

There you go. Let's come up with a generic action that logs stuff:

```
auto action = [](auto type) {
    return [=](auto& ctx){
        auto& attr = _attr(ctx);
        using A = std::decay_t<decltype(attr)>;

        std::cout << type << ":";
        if constexpr(boost::fusion::traits::is_sequence<A>::value) {
            std::cout << boost::fusion::as_vector(attr);
        } else if constexpr(x3::traits::is_container<A>::value && not std::is_same_v<std::string, A>) {
            std::string_view sep;
            std::cout << "{";
            for (auto& el : attr) { std::cout << sep << el; sep = ", "; }
            std::cout << "}";
        } else {
            std::cout << attr;
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    };
};
```

Now we can parse all the samples (plus a few more):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/741f93cfcf246be7)** prints:

```
 === "a"
normal:a
Ok
 === "a()"
normal:a
call:{}
Ok
 === "a.b"
normal:a
member_access:b
Ok
 === "a.b()"
normal:a
member_access:b
call:{}
Ok
 === "a.b().c"
normal:a
member_access:b
call:{}
member_access:c
Ok
 === "a().b.c()"
normal:a
call:{}
member_access:b
member_access:c
call:{}
Ok
 === "a().b.c()"
normal:a
call:{}
member_access:b
member_access:c
call:{}
Ok
 === "a(q,r,s).b"
normal:a
call:{q, r, s}
member_access:b
Ok
```

### SA #2: Building an AST

Let's model the AST:

```
namespace Ast {
    using name   = std::string;
    using params = std::vector<name>;

    struct member_access;
    struct call;

    using lvalue = boost::variant<
        name,
        boost::recursive_wrapper<member_access>,
        boost::recursive_wrapper<call>
    >;

    using params = std::vector<name>;
    struct member_access { lvalue obj; name member; } ;
    struct call          { lvalue f; params args;   } ;
}
```

Now we can replace the actions:

```
auto lvalue
    = rule<struct lvalue_, Ast::lvalue> {"lvalue"}
    = name [ ([](auto& ctx){ _val(ctx) = _attr(ctx); }) ] >> *(
        '.' >> name [ ([](auto& ctx){ _val(ctx) = Ast::member_access{ _val(ctx), _attr(ctx) }; }) ]
      | ('(' >> paralistopt >> ')') [ ([](auto& ctx){ _val(ctx) = Ast::call{ _val(ctx), _attr(ctx) }; }) ]
    );
```

> That's *ugly* - I don't recommend writing your code this way, but at least it drives home how few steps are involved.

Also adding some output operators:

```
namespace Ast { // debug output
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Ast::member_access const& ma) {
        return os << ma.obj << "." << ma.member;
    }
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Ast::call const& c) {
        std::string_view sep;
        os << c.f << "(";
        for (auto& arg: c.args) { os << sep << arg; sep = ", "; }
        return os << ")";
    }
}
```

Now can parse everything with full AST: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0fef1087a223d3bb)**, printing:

```
"a" -> a
"a()" -> a()
"a.b" -> a.b
"a.b()" -> a.b()
"a.b().c" -> a.b().c
"a().b.c()" -> a().b.c()
"a().b" -> a().b
"a(q,r,s).b" -> a(q, r, s).b
```

### Automatic Propagation

Actually I sort of got stranded doing this. It took me too long to get it right and parse the associativity in a useful way, so I stopped trying. Let's instead summarize by cleaning up out second SA take:

### Summary

Making the actions more readable:

```
auto passthrough =
    [](auto& ctx) { _val(ctx) = _attr(ctx); };
template <typename T> auto binary_ =
    [](auto& ctx) { _val(ctx) = T { _val(ctx), _attr(ctx) }; };

auto lvalue
    = rule<struct lvalue_, Ast::lvalue> {"lvalue"}
    = name [ passthrough ] >> *(
        '.' >> name                 [ binary_<Ast::member_access> ]
      | ('(' >> paralistopt >> ')') [ binary_<Ast::call> ]
    );
```

Now there are a number of issues left:

You might want a more general expression grammar that doesn't just parse lvalue expressions (e.g. `f(foo, 42)` should probably parse, as should `len("foo") + 17`?).

To that end, the lvalue/rvalue distinction doesn't belong in the grammar: it's a semantic distinction mostly.

> I happen to have created an extended parser that does all that + evaluation against proper LValues (while supporting general values). I'd suggest looking at the [extended chat][3] at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60846101/85371) and the resulting code  on github: https://github.com/sehe/qi-extended-parser-evaluator .

### Full Listing

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0db6b64b6b279168)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/home/x3.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
namespace x3 = boost::spirit::x3;

namespace Ast {
    using name   = std::string;
    using params = std::vector<name>;

    struct member_access;
    struct call;

    using lvalue = boost::variant<
        name,
        boost::recursive_wrapper<member_access>,
        boost::recursive_wrapper<call>
    >;

    using params = std::vector<name>;
    struct member_access { lvalue obj; name member; } ;
    struct call          { lvalue f; params args;   } ;
}

namespace Ast { // debug output
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Ast::member_access const& ma) {
        return os << ma.obj << "." << ma.member;
    }
    static inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Ast::call const& c) {
        std::string_view sep;
        os << c.f << "(";
        for (auto& arg: c.args) { os << sep << arg; sep = ", "; }
        return os << ")";
    }
}

namespace Parser {
    using namespace x3;

    auto name
        = rule<struct string_, Ast::name> {"name"}
        = lexeme[alpha >> *(alnum|char_("_"))];

    auto paralistopt
        = rule<struct params_, Ast::params> {"params"}
        = -(name % ',');

    auto passthrough =
        [](auto& ctx) { _val(ctx) = _attr(ctx); };
    template <typename T> auto binary_ =
        [](auto& ctx) { _val(ctx) = T { _val(ctx), _attr(ctx) }; };

    auto lvalue
        = rule<struct lvalue_, Ast::lvalue> {"lvalue"}
        = name [ passthrough ] >> *(
            '.' >> name                 [ binary_<Ast::member_access> ]
          | ('(' >> paralistopt >> ')') [ binary_<Ast::call> ]
        );

    auto start = skip(space) [ lvalue ];
}

int main() {
    for (std::string const input: {
            "a",       // special (but ok because rule in grammer)
            "a()",
            "a.b",     // special
            "a.b()",
            "a.b().c", // special
            "a().b.c()",
            "a().b",   // special
             "a(q,r,s).b",
        })
    {
        std::cout << std::quoted(input) << " -> ";

        auto f = begin(input), l = end(input);
        Ast::lvalue parsed;
        if (parse(f, l, Parser::start, parsed)) {
            std::cout << parsed << "\n";;
        } else {
            std::cout << "Failed\n";
        }
        if (f!=l) {
            std::cout << " -- Remainig: " << std::quoted(std::string(f,l)) << "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

Prints

```
"a" -> a
"a()" -> a()
"a.b" -> a.b
"a.b()" -> a.b()
"a.b().c" -> a.b().c
"a().b.c()" -> a().b.c()
"a().b" -> a().b
"a(q,r,s).b" -> a(q, r, s).b
```

¹ (they lead to a mess in the presence of backtracking, see [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil))

Comment: In the off-chance that you were actually using Qi (you didn't say): **[Qi version](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ddb5a2f5123d89d0)** or **[Alternative take](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3O8M1qSXJhjcyvAi)**

Comment: thank you for the good sample .. i add more details in the original post. Maybe i was not clear enough about the topic here. The Goal is to detect and produce a special AST-Node when the input ends with just a ".name". (named in the additional sample as SPECIAL_DOT)

Comment: Doing the replies here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217164/parsers